# How to make order of properties in a property grid differ from the order of properties in class declaration

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, propertygrid

I want to have below class properties to be displayed in PropertyGrid not in the declared order, instead specified attribute? is there such attribute for?

As:

A
B
C

Thanks.

```
    public class ApplicationConfiguration
    {
        public ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
        }
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute has Order property

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending this object from an MVC/WCF application you can use DataMember attribute like below

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration
    {
        public ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
        }
        [DataMember(Order=1)]
        public int A { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public int C { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int B { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options in deciding how instances of your classes should appear in the property grid. Start off with [Design-Time Attributes for Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) and go from there.

See [Extending Design-Time Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx) for the big picture. The bottom line is that you can easily cause your properties to display grouped by categories just by adding `[Category("categoryName")]` attributes. But if you need them to appear in a completely different order from their order of declaration, then you need to create a Designer.